# AngularJS: Function in controller is called three times

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a controller which calls a save service, and it is for some reason triggered three times. It is not that great if it saves three instances every time it is triggered. Is my approach of solving it wrong?

I found this following [article](https://daveceddia.com/controller-function-executed-multiple-times/) which says it is a normal behavior in AngularJS

Below is an example which triggers that behavior. I'm using webpack to bundle AngularJS, and other dependencies.

**FooCtrl**

```
import {IFooService} from "./FooService";

export class FooCtrl {

    static $inject = ["FooService"];

    public fooService: IFooService;

    constructor(fooService: IFooService) {
        console.log("creating foo controller");
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    public callService(): boolean {
        console.log("call service");
        this.fooService.save();
        console.log(this.fooService.getSaves());
        return true;
    }
}
```

**FooService**

```
export interface IFooService {
    save(): void;
    getSaves(): number;
}

export class FooService implements IFooService{

    private saves: number = 0;

    public save(): void {
        console.log("saved");
        this.saves++;
    }

    public getSaves(): number {
        return this.saves;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
namespace Main {

    let fooModule = new FooModule.Module();

    let main = angular.module("myApp", [
        "ngRoute",
        fooModule.getFooModule(),
    ]);

    main.controller("BarCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Bar";
    });

    main.config(function($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            "templateUrl": "foo/index.html",
        });
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.part.html**

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl as ctrl">
    <p ng-bind="ctrl.callService()"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are binding your method to the `<p>` element, it will be trigger on every digest cycle so that angular can check if the value changed.

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but it looks like this this method should be trigger by a user action or maybe periodically and controlled using `$timeout` service.

Read more about scope digest cycle in the official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

Comment: It was only for testing purpose I used `{{ }}` before which also produced the same error. But I found out for testing purpose in my case, I should have used `ng-click` instead, which also applies to my implementation use case.

Comment: `{{ }}` would have same effect as `ng-bind`, angular has to go and check if the value changed and the HTML should be re-rendered. `ng-click` makes sense